# Icon for pinned tabs in Safari?

Tags: feature-request, design, favicon, safari

It would be nice to [have an icon](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/pinnedTabs/pinnedTabs.html) for [pinned tabs in Safari](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH21462?locale=en_US).

As it is, SE kind of stands out (in a not cool way):

[image]

Comment: I'm curious why it doesn't. In general, that seems to be designated as the site's favicon.